# What kind of applications can be written with Qt + Enginio

Tags: qt

I'm totally confused about what kind of applications can I write If I learn how to use Enginio. This is what the [Enginio](https://engin.io/) site says:

> With Enginio, you can create stunning Qt applications, add a scalable
>   and powerful Qt cloud backend as a service in no time and deploy in
>   minutes without ever bothering about backend servers or scalability
>   problems.

Can I think of Enginio as a remote `QFile` or is it much more bigger? Can someone name some samples written with Qt + Enginio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a new service still in development, hence there isn't a tag for it, yet.

From the website, it looks like they provide you with some of the common things all applications need, and provide an interface for qt. You can basically create whatever you want.

Instead of providing only a remote file, they also let you store json objects, lowering some of the impedance between object and file.

Probably not too many examples with this new thing. Maybe you can ask them to provide more samples.